# Python 2.3 multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, global-variables, multiprocessing, python-2.3

Is there any multiprocessing type module for Python 2.3?  I am stuck using 2.3 for the programs I interface with and would like to be able to setup some multiprocessing as the tasks I do only use one CPU and are really inefficient.

I would like each thread/process to handle its own global variables and each thread/process should not share any variables with any other thread/process.  Basically I would just like to have a queue of files that need be run through a function and each run would be an entirely new thread.

I have tried using `thread.start_new_thread`, but it just turned into a mess with my global variables.

A thought just occurred to me, can I do a `os.popen('python C:\function_dir\function.py vars...')` from each new thread?  Sounds rather ugly, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.  The master program wouldn't continue until the `os.popen` "thread" finishes correct?

Any thoughts or modules I may be overlooking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None that I ever found anywhere, I have since moved on to python 2.5

Answer (score 0):

Use **threading**. You simply need to build a class based on **Thread**:

```
import threading

class myThread(threading.Thread):
    #
    # Constructor.
    #
    def __init__(self, ...):
        #
        # Call threading constructor.
        #
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        #
        # Your constructor code.
        #
        ...
    #
    # The code executed when starting the thread.
    #
    def run(self):
        ...
#
# Create an instance and start the thread.
#
myThread(...).start()
```

Make sure to keep all your variables local. If you need to access global variables use the **global** statement:

```
counter = 0

class myThread(threading.Thread):
    ...
    def run(self):
        global counter
        ...
        counter = 17
...
```

For locking, etc. have a look at the Python documentation as well: http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/lib/module-threading.html